# Export an app from Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, export, import

Long ago, I downloaded an extention from the Google Chrome Store. Currently, that extension is not available in the Google Chrome Store, but present and working fine in my computer. Anyhow, if I sync another computer with my Google Chrome account, all other extensions are transferred but not this one.

I have a friend who wants this particular extension. Is it possible in any way that I export this extension from my computer (in some format) and then import into his computer?

Note: The extension works both online and offline.

OS: Windows 7

Comment: Please let me know which OS you're on..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Figure out the the ID of the extension. If the extension has a settings link, click it and observe the long string of characters in the address. For example, Adblock Plus has the page `chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/options.html` and consequently, its ID is `cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb`. Failing this, you can right click somewhere on the area belonging to the extension on the `chrome://extensions/` page, select inspect element—you may need to do thi twice for some reason—and look for the ID there.

[image: Chrome extension ID]

2) Navigate to the folder where the extension is located. On Windows Vista and above, this is `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`. You should be able to copy and paste that string into the run dialog to go directly to the correct directory. Now copy the relevant directory over to the target computer, to some convenient place like the desktop.

3) On the target computer, go to `chrome://extensions/`, enable developer mode and click load unpacked extension. Navigate to the folder below the first folder, showing the version number. This is the same folder that contains the manifest file, `manifest.json`. There's also the option to pack an extension into a single file format that you can drag and drop onto the `chrome://extensions/` in order to install the extension on another computer.

[image: Load unpacked extension]

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 7, the extensions path is:

```
C:\Users\*UserName*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

On linux, Chrome extensions are stored in:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/
```

Or [this](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.chromeplugins.org/google/chrome-tips-tricks/i-have-2-computers-my-bookmarks-synchronized-now-how-about-extensions-2-8873.html#post20509&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHI1HD_p1aiUFWJNkAjvnsVshqAeQ) thread might help you.

You'll find the extension folders.

Best of luck!